# Java find three num in array

Tags: java, arrays, find

**Task:** Given an array of int's, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other, otherwise return false.

This is my current code:

```
 public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int item) {
  for (int n : arr) {
     if (item == n) {
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int item) {
    // Count of number of occurences
    int count=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr.length-1 == i){
        if(arr[i] == item)
          count++;
     }else {
        if (arr[i] == item &&  arr[i] + 1 == item)
            return false;
        if(arr[i] == item)
            count++;
           }
        }
       return count == 3;
    }
```

Comment: Okay,but where is the other parts of the program?

Comment: Are you looking for the code to accept input and all that ? You should be able to do that. We have given you the logic for the method..

Comment: @S.Mac it looks good, now all you have do in the main method, you have to use one of the answers given here and pass in the array a and the number three. So something like System.out.println(contains(a, 3)); would come after int a [] = getArray();

Comment: Thank u!Its is Works!!U were very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the array and count the number of times the item arrays. Also, you need to keep track of whether the previous item was the one you were looking for or not. E.g.:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int item) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean prev = false;
    for (int n : arr) {
        if (n == item) {
            if (prev) {
                return false;
            }
            ++count;
            prev = true;
            if (count > 3) { // Optimization - could be removed
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            prev = false;
        }
    }
    return count == 3;
}
```

Comment: Okay,but where is the other parts of the program?

Comment: I was just looking at your code and could not figure out how you were doing the check for the next value, and I stepped through it, and that is a clever solution good job!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Look at the following revision in your code:

```
 public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int item) {
  int count=0;
  for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
     if (item == arr[i]) {
        if(i+1 < arr.length && item == arr[i+1])
           return false;
        else count++;
     }
  }

  return (count == 3);
}
```

Comment: Okay,but where is the other parts of the program?

Comment: you can simplify the last line to return count === 3

Comment: @EduardoDennis, absolutely. I just edited it. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> public static contains(int[] arr) {
>  int index = -2;
>  int count = 0;
>  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>    if (arr[i] == 3) {
>     if (i-1 != index) {
>       index = i;
>       count++;
>     } else {
>       contains = false;
>       break;
>     }
>  }
>
>  if (count != 3) {
>   contains = false;
>  }
>  return contains;
> }
> ```

Comment: the method needs to accept the number that is being looked for.

Comment: In your question you said SPECIFICALLY "3", and did not say anything about accepting number that is being looked for.